# Pdf C# mvc Rotativa

Tags: c#, mvc, pdf, rotativa

Tengo una consulta, estoy realizando un **PDF** en **C# MVC**. Lo que tengo que hacer es que se muestren datos en el **PDF** que se genera. Pero, tengo dos inconvenientes.

**Primero:** necesito que ese **PDF** sea de 5 (cinco) páginas pero cada página debe tener distintas imágenes. Es decir: hoja 1 (uno) con imagen a, hoja 2 (dos) con imagen b y así hasta la hoja 5 (cinco) de ese **PDF**.

**Segundo:** necesito que los valores que se muestran en la hoja 1 (uno) del **PDF** se vizualicen también en la hoja 2 (dos) del **PDF**.

No se si me estoy dando a entender bien, cualquier cosa lo aclaro de otra forma. Adjunto el código de lo que tengo hecho hasta ahora:

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-image: url("/Images/48-60/01.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

p.cic {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 4em;
    margin-top: 12.8em;
    font-size: 20px;
}

p.plan {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 13.65em;
    margin-top: 16em;
}
```

**Nota:** El `CSS` es mucho más largo, por lo que solo muestro la carga de una imagen y la ubicación de dos datos.

**Vista:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Solicitudes.Models.Solicitud>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Plan 48</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Estilos/const48.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" method="get" action="/Home/Pdf">
        <br />
        <div>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <p class="cic">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.DniNumero)</p>

                <p class="plan">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Codigo)</p>

                <p class="valorCuota">$@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Monto)</p>

                <p class="derechoSuscripcion">$@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Monto)</p>

                <p class="check">✔</p>

                <p class="solicitud">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Solicitudes)</p>

                <p class="fechaSol">Fecha</p>

                <p class="valNom">$@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.ValNom)</p>

                <p class="descripcion">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.DescPlanActual)</p>

                <p class="apellido">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Apellido)</p>

                <p class="nombre">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Nombre)</p>

                <p class="calle">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Domicilio)</p>

                <p class="numeroCalle">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Numero)</p>

                <p class="dpto">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Dpto) - @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Piso) - @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=>item.Mono)</p>

                <p class="barrio">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Barrio)</p>

                <p class="zona">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.acidzona)</p>

                <p class="localidad">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Localidad)</p>

                <p class="provincia">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Provincia)</p>

                <p class="codpostal">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=>item.CodigoPostal)</p>

                <p class="tipoDoc">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=>item.DniTipo)</p>

                <p class="dni">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=>item.DniNumero)</p>

                <p class="fechNac">25/07/1994</p>

                <p class="ocupacion">Ocupacion</p>

                <p class="tel">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem =>item.Telefono)</p>

                <p class="cel">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=>item.Celular)</p>

                <p class="fechRec">18/06/2020</p>

                <p class="email">prueba@gmail.com</p>

                <p class="estado">Soltero</p>

                <p class="observaciones">Viernes Chico</p>

                <p class="nombreCompleto">Suarez, Pepito</p>

                <p class="tipodos">DU</p>

                <p class="dniDos">38330252</p>

                <p class="codAg">005ASD</p>

                <p class="codCobr">005ASD</p>

                <p class="control">Suarez, Fulana</p>
            }
        </div>
    </form>
    
    <form>
        <div>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <p class="asesor">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.asesor)</p>
                <p class="invisible">esto es una prueba del area de sistemas</p>
            }
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controlador:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Pdf(string solicitud) 
        {
            try 
            {
                ConexionSQL c = new ConexionSQL();

                // usar inlinne para ver online - attachment para descarga automática
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + solicitud + ".pdf\"");

                var suscriptor = c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud);
                var caracteres = Convert.ToString(solicitud).Length;
                if (suscriptor.Count <= 0)
                {
                    ViewBag.Alert = "Lo sentimos, la soliciud ingresada no existe.";
                    return View("Index");
                }
                if (suscriptor[0].cantCuo == 48)
                {
                    return new PartialViewAsPdf("Pdf48o60", c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud))
                    {
                        RotativaOptions = new Rotativa.Core.DriverOptions
                        {
                            PageMargins = new Rotativa.Core.Options.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)
                        }
                    };
                }
                else if (suscriptor[0].cantCuo == 60)
                {
                    return new PartialViewAsPdf("Pdf40o60", c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud))
                    {
                        RotativaOptions = new Rotativa.Core.DriverOptions
                        {
                            PageMargins = new Rotativa.Core.Options.Margins(0, 0, 0, 0)
                        }
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData["Mensaje"] = "Lo sentimos, no existe un plan de cuotas para esta solicitud.";
                    return View("Index");
                }
            } 
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                return Content("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Entonces, retomando, ¿Cómo hago para que cada página tenga su propia imagen? Y, ¿Cómo hago para duplicar los datos de la hoja 1 (uno) en la hoja 2 (dos)?
¿Alguien puede ayudarme?
¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo? Tu escenario está interesante. ¿En dónde debería estar la imagen?

Comment: Intenté agregando las imágenes al `css` pero no ha funcionado. Cada imagen, debe ocupar toda la hoja del pdf. Es decir, son hojas de formulario. En la hoja uno, vemos la imagen del formulario con los datos cargados, este formulario es de color azul. En la segunda hoja, vemos el mismo formulario, que debe tener los mismos datos, pero esta vez el formulario es de color gris. En la hoja 3 la imagen habla de la cantidad de pagos, en la hoja 4 leyes, etc. @fredyfx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución temporal fue inluir muchas etiquetas 
 para así conseguir lo que se pedía